# My WiFi network adapter has disappeared from device manager

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, asus

1. This laptop ASUS P5440FA has no connection to wifi. The wifi adapter does not appear in device manager or in network adapters. Bluetooth is also missing.
2. Scanning for hardware changes does not detect the wifi adapter or Bluetooth.
3. I have tried downloading and reinstalling the drivers from the ASUS website for this model and still the wifi adapter is not detected.
4. I have tried the Intel driver update assistant which does not find the wifi adapter either.
5. This suddenly happened after making a change in the Power Settings control panel because the system was shutting down without explanation. The system was working fine for 4 months before this.
6. The system is up-to-date with all Windows updates.
7. Sfc has not detected any issues. DISM is up-to date.

Comment: Are they enabled within BIOS/UEFI? Sometimes if wireless is disabled there, the hardware will not show up in the hardware manager.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a hardware failure.

~ "the system was shutting down without explanation."

Unfortunately this sounds like you are experiencing a cooling system failure. It could be as easy as a clogged fan or heatsink, and getting a can of compressed air to clean out the heatsink fins.

It could be the CPU fan is coming to it's end of service life, or the computer requires a re-paste of thermal compound in-between the cpu and heat sink, or all of the above.

If this system was running hot for long periods of time, it could have reduced the lifetime of the card, causing an eventual failure.

You have a couple options, you can replace the internal card with a new one for around $12-25usd depending on where you purchase it from. If you have never done this before, take it to a shop and let someone else do it. (These computers from asus usually have alot of plastic for the frame, and plastic tabs to release, that sound like it's breaking when you open it up. It's not for the faint of heart)

You could just purchase a USB Wlan card to replace the lost functionality, without the need to go on a internal hardware adventure. I would still try to clean the cooling system the best you can though.

~Best Regards